# Any alternative to the gnome3 desktop-profile-manager extension?

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, gnome-shell-extension

I am looking for a way to easily change profiles between three environments with different monitor setups, I regularly plug my laptop in.

Currently I have 3 monitors.xml files, that I switch each time via cli, but this extension:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/688/display-profile-manager/

looks perfect for my usecase, but is not maintained anymore.

Any known alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

Lacking an extension, you could brew a little dialog yourself using Zenity (installed by default on Ubuntu), or using Rofi or dmenu, in a script that can be summoned using an application launcher (Zenity, less "natural" for rofi/dmenu) or using a custom shortcut key.